# Change direction of validation message from wpf error.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation, xaml, mvvm

When my textbox's validation is triggered as an error, the message automatically appears on the right. Is there a way to reconfigure this so that it appears on the left or top of the textbox?

When it appears, it blocks access to another control.

Comment: Could you upload screen of it?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/dHTiG)
Behind the red box, there's  a checkbox that I'd like to be selectable

Comment: This is easily discoverable.  See the section "Specifying a Custom Validation Style" here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf/ that will lead you to other resources.  Try something and come back when you have problems.